# Aplicacion de Escritorio WPF y SqLite

Tags: c#

Soy muy nuevo programando y muy muy inexperto.

Me lance a programar una aplicacion de escritorio en WPF con C# y como base de datos utilizo SQLite ya que los datos que manejo son bien simples y no requiero de un gestor de base de datos mas potente.

Dentro de mi solucion decido incluir una clase para manipular la base de datos la cual es la siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Data;

namespace DashEnt
{
    class DbMani
   {
    private String cadena = "data source=DbDash.db";
    public SQLiteConnection cn;
    private SQLiteCommandBuilder cmb;
    public DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    public SQLiteDataAdapter da;
    public SQLiteCommand comando;

    private void conectar()
    {
        cn = new SQLiteConnection(cadena);
    }

    public DbMani()
    {
        conectar();
    }

    //Metodo para Consultas

    public void consultar(string sql, string tabla)
    {
        ds.Tables.Clear();
        da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, cn);
        cmb = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(da);
        da.Fill(ds, tabla);
    }

    //Metodo para Eliminar

    public bool eliminar(string tabla, string condicion)
    {
        cn.Open();
        string sql = "delete from " + tabla + " where " + condicion;
        comando = new SQLiteCommand(sql, cn);
        int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
        if (i > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Metodo para Actualizar

    public bool actualizar(string tabla, string campos, string condicion)
    {
        cn.Open();
        string sql = "update " + tabla + " set " + campos + " where " + condicion;
        comando = new SQLiteCommand(sql, cn);
        int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
        if (i > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Metodo consultas para combos

    public DataTable consucom(string tabla)
    {
        string sql = "select * from " + tabla;
        da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, cn);
        DataSet dts = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(dts, tabla);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = dts.Tables[tabla];
        return dt;
    }

    //Metodo para insertar datos

    public bool insertar(string sql)
    {
        cn.Open();
        comando = new SQLiteCommand(sql, cn);
        int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
        if (i > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Hasta aqui todo parece normal, en el formulario principal tengo un datagrid, instancio la clase antes citada de la siguiente manera:

```
DbMani obDatos = new DbMani();
```

Cuando carga el formulario quiero que se rellene el datagrid, para esto hago lo siguiente:

```
private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        obDatos.consultar("select * from TabBitacora", "TabBitacora");
        this.dataApp.ItemsSource = obDatos.ds.Tables["TabBitacora"];

    }
```

y he aqui el error que me indica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Perdon por la captura tan mala, basicamente lo que me indica el error es:

> (Campo)System.Data.DataSet.DbMani.ds  No se pude convertir
>   implicitamente el tipo System.Data.DataTable en
>   System.Collections.|Enumerable. Ya existe una conversion explicita
>   (compruebe si le falta alguna conversion)

Seguro que estoy haciendo una burrada, ¿alguien podria indicarme cual?

Muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: proba agregando a IsEnumerable

Comment: Tambien podrías intentar con un ToList()

Comment: Muchas gracias gbianchi, Ivan-San por su rapida respuesta, pero como puedo implementar lo que me indican.

Comment: Oye hermano , tu codigo me deja confuso.
Mi recomendacion, hace dias lo hice y funciona ok.
usa entity framework para ese pequeño proyecto , en youtube hay muchos tutoriales benissimos para eso , y te ahorras muuuuucho codigo : mira este video.y triunfaras con sqlite y c# https://youtu.be/0E4KW69kpMU

Comment: `this.dataApp.ItemsSource = obDatos.ds.Tables["TabBitacora"].AsEnumerable();`

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago todo mediante un DataReader y me funciona de maravilla sin embargo yo tengo las columnas fijas en el grid y por eso lo hago asi

```
SQL = "Select act,cnf,nam,pul,pud,dol,dod,car,rat,ins,cid,sor,fecha_procesado from tb_wizard_layout where impreso IS NULL";
    try
    {
        oComando.Connection = CC;
        oComando.CommandText = SQL;
        oDataReader = oComando.ExecuteReader();
        oComando.Dispose();
    }
    catch (NpgsqlException ErrorCons)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ErrorCons.Message);
    }
    while(oDataReader.Read())
    {
        DGVReport.Rows.Add(oDataReader["act"], oDataReader["cnf"], oDataReader["nam"], oDataReader["pul"], oDataReader["pud"], oDataReader["dol"], oDataReader["dod"], oDataReader["car"], oDataReader["rat"], oDataReader["cid"], oDataReader["sor"], oDataReader["fecha_procesado"]);              
    }
    CC.Close();
```

Pero anterior para hacerlo como tu quieres tambien lo puedes realizar de la siguiente manera

```
    SQL = "Select act,cnf,nam,pul,pud,dol,dod,car,flt,rat,ins,cid,mop,cmp,ad1,ad2,ad3,dlc,sor,fecha_procesado from tb_wizard_layout where impreso IS NULL";
    NpgsqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(SQL, CC);
    DataAdapter.Fill(ReportDataSet);
    DGVReport.DataSource = ReportDataSet.Tables[0];
    CC.Close();
```

De esta manera te carga en automatico los datos sobre un grid limpio